# Using a backup disk made in Windows Vista to reinstall programs an files in Ubuntu

Tags: backup, compatibility, windows-vista

I'm getting ready to transfer over to Ubuntu from Windows Vista.  I was wondering if I could use a backup disc made in Windows Vista (using the default backup/restore program) to restore the files to Ubuntu once I wipe the hard drive clean and install Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

You can copy your data to a USB Flash Drive, USB hard disk,or to CD/DVD, then copy to Ubuntu.

Or, see this article: [How to Migrate from Windows to Ubuntu](http://www.wikihow.com/Migrate-from-Windows-to-Ubuntu)

> When migrating from Windows to Ubuntu, there are a few things you
>   might need to reflect over, like how to cope the new system, the new
>   interface, and how to adapt to Ubuntu in general, and of course, how
>   to transfer your personal files over to the new OS. The article shows
>   you how.

Source: http://www.wikihow.com/Migrate-from-Windows-to-Ubuntu